# mount cloud storage under Linux via socks?

Tags: linux, mount, webdav, socks

I'm trying to mount cloud storage under Linux, but via a SOCKS proxy.

One suggested solution I found is to use `davfs2`, but as far as I can tell it only supports a Http Proxy. I've tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install davfs2

#enable the following in /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf
use_proxy       1
proxy 192.168.147.1:100  #my socks proxy

# add the following to /etc/fstab
https://dav.box.com/dav /home/user/box.com davfs rw,user,noauto 0 0

# then try to mount
mount box.com
```

However it can never connect. I'm assuming because it's expecting a HTTP proxy. Error thrown is:

> Could not create SSL connection through proxy server: Could not read status line: connection was closed by proxy server

So can anyone suggest either a way to get this to work? Or an alternative way to mount it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `socksify`? It might be able to do the job since it's a userspace filesystem.

If that doesn't work install a shim proxy that takes HTTP requests and forwards them to a SOCKS proxy.

I'm sure there's an easier way but running `socksify` on squid would do the job. Then point davfs2 at squid.